# Downvoting shouldn't be so easy

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is something I (luckily) rarely have to deal with, but a lot of times I stumble upon very interesting question here, which get good or not so super-precise or explicitly detailed answers.

Often in life, a simple meme (original meaning) is enough to lead someone to the goal he strives for, but those answers won't be tolerated in this community and that's honestly a shame.

Users in this community tend to rate answers down. The ratio of upvote/downvote seems like some of our users are just out to stone somebody.

Downvoting a question is too easy. It's just a click.
The reason why people downvote is often because of missing details or explanations, but ironically downvoting requires none explanation at all.

You basically kill some, that killed someone, because you're against killing.

I really wish that downvoting should be not so easy or only open for veterans.
Downvoting with no reason should be paid with reputation.

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: Bad questions and answers create a terrible noise. My only complaint is that they aren't culled quick enough.

Comment: "*Users in this community tend to rate answers down.*" They do? Where? Oh, we downvote garbage answers (such as [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56150/can-i-use-a-certain-song-in-my-credits-as-long-as-i-credit-the-original-author/56160#56160) and [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55299/game-dev-question/55303#55303), but in general, the ratio of downvotes to upvotes is *staggeringly* in favor of upvotes.

Comment: "*You basically kill some, that killed someone, because you're against killing.*" ... what? I don't even see the logic there. Posting a crap question and downvoting are *two different things*. Posting a crap question harms *the site* as a whole; downvoting a post only hurts that post. So your analogy doesn't even work.

Comment: "*only open for veterans*" 125 rep is not hard to get, even here. Granted, if you can't contribute useful answers or decent questions, it will be hard to get. But that's only because you're not being very useful to the site, not because you're not a "veteran".

Answer (score 5):

Downvoting answers costs reputation. Downvoting questions used to, but was [recently changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free). You're better off having this discussion over there.

Comment: From the link it was clear what you meant, but thought I should fix the text.  :)

Comment: lol >_< thanks.